# Is this solution bounded for every $t>0$ for this Bernouli Equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

I'm trying to solve the following initial value problem.

$$ \begin{cases}
y'=y-y^3,\ t>0 \\
y(0)= \frac{1}{2}
\end{cases} $$

Consider whether their solutions remain bounded for every $t ≥ 0$. If not, you can
determine the 'burst time'.

**Solution**

We Solve the Bernoulli equation $\dfrac{dy(t)}{dt}-y(t)= - y(t)^3,\ t>0$ (1), such that $y(0) = \frac{1}{2}$.

We set $$v=y^{1-3}$$
Then we solve for y, which gives $$y=v^{-\frac{1}{2}}\,(2).$$
We differentiate the (2), so we have  that
$$\frac{dy}{dt}=-\frac{1}{2}v^{-\frac{3}{2}}\frac{dv}{dt}.$$

We plug all those into equation (1) and we have
$$-\frac{1}{2}v^{-\frac{3}{2}}\frac{dv}{dt}-v^{-\frac{1}{2}}=-(v^{-\frac{1}{2}})^3$$

We multiply both sides by $-2v^{\frac{3}{2}}$ and we received
$$\frac{dv}{dt}+2v=2.$$

Let $$p(t)=e^{\int 2 dt}=e^{2t} $$

Multiply both sides with p(t) so we have:
$$\frac{dv}{dt}e^{2t}+e^{2t}2v=2e^{2t}$$
We integrate
$$\int (e^{2t}v)' \, dt= \int 2 e^{2t} dt $$ and we have
$$e^{2t}v=\frac{2e^{2t}v}{2}+c.$$ Then we solve for v
$$v=1+c e^{-2t}.$$ Finally we solve for y and our solution is $$y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+c e^{-2t}}}$$

Then we plug in  the initial condition $y(0) = \frac{1}{2}$ and we find that
$$y(t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+3e^{-2 t } }}$$

$$ 1+3e^{-2 t } \geq 0\Leftrightarrow e^{2t}\leq -3$$

My question Is this solution bounded or what is the burst time?
I have tried to find the domain of the solution but it doesn't give me an interval

Comment: @LutzLehmann any help with this? Thank you

Comment: Your solution is correct. As $\mathrm e^{-2t}>0$ for all $t$, the mathematical domain of your solution function is all of $\mathbb R$ and there is no burst time and your solution is bounded: You can e.g. check that it admits no critical points and it is strictly increasing, so the bound is given by $\lim\limits_{t\to\infty}y(t) = 1$.

Comment: Or more generally, you have constant solution with values $0$ and $1$, and due to uniqueness no other solution crosses these. So the solution with $y(0)=1/2$ remains between these two lines in both directions, extending thus to $\pm\infty$.